# Запрос на соединение по одинаковому значению в первом столбце

Tags: mysql, sql

Собственно, есть запрос вида:

```
SELECT CONCAT (test_name.name,'_', measuring.pinname) as name_test,
measuring.meas FROM measuring, test_name WHERE measuring.id_test = test_name.id
ORDER BY `name_test` DESC
```

На выходе получаю таблицу вида:

```
test_name 1    значение 1  
test_name 1    значение 2  
test_name 1    значение n    
....  
test_name n    значение 1  
....  
test_name n    значение n
```

Есть ли вариант получить вид:

```
test_name 1 значение 1, значение 2, ...., значение n  
....  
test_name n значение 1, значение 2, ...., значение n?
```

В целом делаю это для будущего расчета матрицы корреляции.

Comment: Конечно есть. Прочитайте про [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html), а конкретнее, про [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Конкретнее - есть вариант получить в первом столбце test_name 1, во втором столбце - через запятую "значение 1", "значение 2" и т.д - одним строковым значением. И так для каждого "test_name i". Или Вам нужно, чтобы именно отдельными столбцами были все значения? Это тоже можно, но сложнее и лучше не надо.

Comment: Скорей второе, так как потом буду вытаскивать эти данные в массив и строить транспонированную матрицу по нему.
Но в целом и из первого варианта вытащить всё в нужный мне формат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Должно получиться что-то вроде:

```
select 
   concat(test_name.name,'_', measuring.pinname) as name_test,
   group_concat(measuring.meas separator ',') as `meas` 
from measuring, test_name where measuring.id_test = test_name.id
group by `name_test`
order by `name_test` desc
```

Пример можно посмотреть в [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87f575/5) (возможно будет долго загружать код, но там рабочий пример)

Comment: сделал вот так:
SELECT DISTINCT    CONCAT(
        test_name.name,
        '_',
        measuring.pinname
    ) AS name_test,
    (
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(measuring.meas) AS v_param
    FROM
        measuring,
        test_name
    WHERE
        measuring.id_test = test_name.id and measuring.id_IMS = 3 AND CONCAT (test_name.name,'_', measuring.pinname) = name_test
) AS v_param
FROM
    measuring,
    test_name
WHERE
    measuring.id_test = test_name.id and measuring.id_IMS = 3

На большой выборке начал жёстко тупить. Минуты 3 грузится, а потом крашится.

Comment: @Depressa, потому что для чего вообще заниматься "этим" в mysql? Вы взяли какую-то свою задачу по расчету какой-то корреляции, затем подумали, что, возможно, её можно разбить на подзадачи каким-то вот "таким" образом - Вы уверены, что такое разбиение основной задачи в принципе разумно и оптимально? Задайте вопрос по изначальной задаче лучше, а не по отдельному кусочку, может Вам что более дельное посоветуют. В принципе, в mysql есть статистические функции. Если не принципиален язык - то в R есть более классные штуки для "всего этого".